# Can someone explain how magnetic potential energy can exist even though the field is non-conservative?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential-energy, magnetic-moment, conservative-field

$U=-B\cdot \mu$ is defined to be the magnetic potential energy, I saw this in my lecture notes, but we had already talked about the fact that since the work done to move a charge there is path dependant, there can not be a unique potential at a point in a magnetic field. So there is no use in defining a magnetic potential energy.

The only thing I have in my notes is that it shows for a current loop, it has the most potential energy when the magnetic moment is perpendicular to the field, and has 0 potential energy when it is parallel. I can sort of justify this by saying it makes sense that the potential should be a maximum in an orientation where there is the most restoring torque on the loop and minimum where there is none

But what does a potential mean in a non conservative field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your confusing a field's scalar "potential" with potential energy. The concepts are related, but in a particular way. Say I have a vector field $\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{x})$. There is a [mathematical theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) that I can break this field down into two two parts
$$\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{x}) = -\nabla \Phi + \nabla\times\mathbf{A},$$
$\Phi$ is something we call $\mathbf{V}$'s scalar potential and $\mathbf{A}$ is its vector potential.

The connection to potential energy comes in *if* we can write a force on some particle is of the form
$$\mathbf{F} = a \mathbf{V}$$
and $\mathbf{A} = 0$, then the potential energy of that particle will be $U = a\Phi$.

So, in the case you're dealing with you don't have a force of needed form, so it's not a problem. Granted, we still have the statement, "The magnetic field can do no work," but showing how that works out in the case of a magnetic dipole like this is subtle. In fact, the force and torque on a magnetic dipole are
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{F} & = \left(\mathbf{\mu}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{B} \text{ and} \\
    \mathbf{\tau} & = \mathbf{\mu}\times \mathbf{B}.
\end{align}
I'm less certain here, but I'm pretty sure you'll find that the combination of those two makes it impossible to harvest infinite energy from any static magnetic field.

Comment: Are you saying the electric field set up by the current loop does the work, and the magnetic potential energy is just a store of the electric fields KE? I dont think I understand your answer, sorry can you please clarify.

Comment: @VishalJain Completely reworked answer. It's possible to make what was said in the old answer relevant, but it requires a bit of work.

Comment: To summarise, you are saying since the vector potential is non zero, the potential energy is not just the scalar potential, which is what gravitational and electric potential is. 
I understand that my definition of potential energy is the issue, but if the potential energy isnt just the scalar potential, what physical significance does the vector potential have. I understand the scalar potential as the work to move a charge from infinity to a point, what analog can be used for the vector potential?

Comment: The magnetic vector potential is difficult to interpret. See, you recall how we can shift the scalar potential by a constant value and no physics changes? Well, it turns out that's a smaller part of something called a "gauge transform" that makes a large chunk of $\mathbf{A}$ arbitrary. Point being, that's a separate question, not a comment on an answer.

Comment: ill cross that bridge when i get to it, thanks